# Interceptor throws an error after sign in to angular7 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I have an `angular7` application in which there are multiple modules and there services too. I have `node.js` back-end and `jwt` authentication mechanism. When token expires on client side , so back-end sends 405 error response to client.

Now on client side i implemented `interceptor` to get that `405` error and redirect to login. Here is my `interceptor` code

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(this.localCache.getToken(), 'token')
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log('succeed');
            }
        }, error => {
            if (error.status == 405) {
                this.appService.navigateToView(Constants.VIEW_ROUTES.LOGIN);
                this.localCache.setTokeExpireErrorMsg('Session Expired');
            }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        })
    )
}
```

But after logging in, on my dashboard there are 3 apis are calling on load. But when user comes to dashboard after login so on dashboard all apis are not getting token even in my local storage token is present and also intercept is throwing an error like this

[image: Intercept Error]

Answer (score 1):

Since every API call passes through the interceptor, you can check if the token is still valid, proceed with the API call

If the token expired, redirect to login and prevent any further API call.

Try like this:

```
intercept(req, next) {
    var token = this.sessionService.getToken();
    if (token == null && this.sessionService.isTokenExpired()) {
      this.sessionService.logOut()
      toastr.warning("Session Timed Out! Please Login");
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      return throwError("Session Timed Out")
    });
} else {

  return next.handle(req).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.status === 405) {
      console.log('in if')
      localStorage.clear();
      this.appService.navigateToView(Constants.VIEW_ROUTES.LOGIN)
      this.localCache.setTokeExpireErrorMsg('Session has expired, please login agian')
    }
    return Observable.throw(err);
  }
}
```

session-service.ts

```
  getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('userToken');
  }

  getTokenExpirationDate(token: string): Date {
    token = this.getToken()
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    if (decoded.exp === undefined) return null;

    const date = new Date(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);
    return date;
  }

  isTokenExpired(token?: string): boolean {
    if (!token) token = this.getToken();
    if (token) return true;

    const date = this.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
    if (date === undefined) return false;
    return !(date.valueOf() > new Date().valueOf());
  }

  logOut(loginType?: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedin');        
  }
```

Comment: should i put this interceptor to my every module's providers array?

Comment: No, it is absolutely fine if you put it only in app.module

Comment: and i want that if there is not token in local storage so in that case also user sould be redirected to login. So how can i achieve that? Additionally look into your `isTokenExpired` method in session-service.ts you are checking the same condition in both ifs.

Comment: `if (token == null && this.sessionService.isTokenExpired())`

Comment: look into your `isTokenExpired` function in `session-service.ts` , you are checkin same condiiton i.e `if (!token)` in both ifs.

Comment: I provided you the idea, please apply the logic as per your requirement. You donot need to paste my code, just take the idea and apply it

Comment: In your code you used `jwt_decode`. So is there any angular library to decode jwt token?

Comment: I have modified it.   :)

Comment: Yes, you should use it, it is very easy to work with jwt

Comment: thanx, Let me try your idea. I am implementing it right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199403/discussion-between-fahad-hassan-subzwari-and-adrita-sharma).

Comment: yes but not working. It's not coming inside interceptor on token expiry. I put a console.log in interceptor

Comment: It should... If possible share your github repo, I will look into it later

Comment: yes it's working now. i was ussing old `http` module in https services that's why interceptor wasn't intercepting http req. Now it's calling interceptor but now it's giving an error on logging in like this `InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified"}
message: "Invalid token specified"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199424/discussion-between-adrita-sharma-and-fahad-hassan-subzwari).